# Copy input into another input BUT remove certain characters in the 2nd input

Tags: javascript

Please read before evaluate!
I know **very well** how to copy one input into another input, but I need something different, I need to remove some characters in the second input, i'm using this example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("one"),
        dst = document.getElementById("two");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value;
    });
};
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" />
```

What I need I think is simple, I only need to allow [a-zA-Z0-9-] in the 2nd input.

So, If I write in "one": Hello, How are you?

I want to see in "two": HelloHowareyou

My apologize for this stupid question, but I don't have too much knowledge on JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have options here, either with the use of `replace()` or `match()`. The example below simply replaces any characters that don't match (using `^` in Regex) with an empty character.

```js
var src = document.getElementById("one"),
    dst = document.getElementById("two");

src.addEventListener('input', function() {
    dst.value = src.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/g, "");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your support @Santi!
Work perfect!